# reg expression to match any html

Tags: php, html, regex

I am trying to write `PHP` code which finds part of `HTML` and replace it with another.
My  start and end points are `<!--top-index-start--> and <!--top-index-end-->` in `HTML` code.
After `PHP` code finds it and replace with `HTML` code from the `ckeditor` form textarea it cant find it any more.

```
$pattern = '/<!--top-index-start-->(.*?)<!--top-index-end-->/';  
$replacement = '<!--top-index-start-->' . $_POST['editor1'] . '<!--top-index-end-->';  
$indexcontent = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $indexcontent);
```

Comment: Have you tried anything - if so let us into peeking at the code

Answer (score 1):

By `it cant find it anymore`, you mean that you cannnot find the content between `<!--top-index-start-->` and `<!--top-index-end-->`?

Sure, you have completely replaced it. It looks to me like you have your capture groups backwards. Try this:

```
$regex = "~(<!--top-index-start-->).*?(<!--top-index-end-->)~";
$replacement = "\1".$_POST['editor1']."\2";
$indexcontent = preg_replace($regex, $replacement, $indexcontent);
```

**Explanation**

The capturing parentheses in the regex capture your top and end delimiters to Groups 1 and 2. In the replacement string, you reference these as `\1` and `\2` to build the replacement.

Comment: Thanks for all. It was an issue of modifiers. I needed 's' modifier to match all inside .*?